# Keep comment author's name on their comment even when their account is deleted

Tags: comments

I noticed when a user leaves a comment but then their account is deleted, their comment stays but their name disappears. Is there a way to keep the comment author's name on their comment even when their account is deleted?

Comment: Wouldn't this also possible violate the upcoming [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation), but I'm not an expert on that ;-) There's a work in progress on how to handle it accordingly in WordPress core.

Comment: This doesn't happen. I just tested on a fresh install to be sure. When a comment is posted the `comment_author` column is filled with the user's display name when making the comment. When the user is deleted this doesn't change. It would only happen if a plugin or theme was filtering the author name to replace it with the user's display name dynamically.

Comment: @jacob-peattie ahh thanks, yes I think I know the culprit. Thanks.

Comment: @birgire in my case the front end author wasn't visible but it was still visible in the backend.